# What is the difference between mixin and ringsize?

Tags: ringsize

The community recently changed from using the term mixin for ring signatures to using ringsize. Are these terms used interchangeably, or are there some differences between these two terms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a small difference. In summary, ringsize will always equal mixin + 1. So, a mixin of 2 is the same as a ringsize of 3.

**Mixin refers to the number of *other* inputs used in a ring signature that you do *not* control.**

**Ringsize refers to the number of *total* inputs used in a ring signature, including ones you control.**

Answer (score 3):

1, the difference is 1 :)

They both refer to the same thing - number of public keys which make the ring signature, however:

- ringsize includes the one-time public key belonging to the originating wallet
- mixin doesn't, and refers only to foreign one-time public keys

So, ringsize = mixin + 1.